# react-native-youtube undefined is not an object "YouTubeStandaloneIOS"

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, youtube, react-native-ios

I am using YouTubeStandaloneIOS. Followed these steps

https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube#standalone-player-ios but no success.

I am using this:

```
import Youtube,
{ YouTubeStandaloneAndroid, YouTubeStandaloneIOS }
from 'react-native-youtube';

YouTubeStandaloneIOS.playVideo('KVZ-P-ZI6W4')
.then(() => console.log('Standalone Player Exited'))
.catch(errorMessage => console.error(errorMessage))
```

My Podfile is:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AppName' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!
  pod 'XCDYouTubeKit', '~> 2.5'
  # Pods for AppName

  target 'AppNameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'AppName-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AppName-tvOS

  target 'AppName-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Tried to use below url code but didn't get the YoutubeStandaloneIOS button.

https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube/blob/master/example/RCTYouTubeExample.js

[image]

[image]